# make_date() not working in a form, getting wrong dates

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript in the header of this site:
https://www.powwows.com/

```
function make_date() {
  var month =
    document.getElementById('srchMonth').value;
  var year =
    document.getElementById('srchYear').value;
  if (month != '' && year == '') {
    date = '2014-' + month + '-01,2023-' + month + '-28';
  }
  if (month == '' && year != '') {
    date = year + '-01-01,' + year + '-12-31';
  }
  if (month != '' && year != '') {
    date = year + '-' + month + '-01,' + year + '-' + month + '-28';
  }
  document.getElementById('scope').value = date; //alert(date); 
}
```

It's supposed to get the dates (scope) for this form:

```
<input type="hidden" value="search_events" name="action">
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="search">
<input type="hidden" name="scope[0]" id="scope" value="">
<select onchange="make_date()" id="srchMonth" class="form-control input-lg" name="srchMonth">
<option value="">Select Month</option>
<option value="01"> January</option>
<option value="02"> February</option>
<option value="03"> March</option>
<option value="04"> April</option>
<option value="05"> May</option>
<option value="06"> June</option>
<option value="07"> July</option>
<option value="08"> August</option>
<option value="09"> September</option>
<option value="10"> October</option>
<option value="11"> November</option>
<option value="12"> December</option>
</select>

<select onchange="make_date()"  id="srchYear" class="form-control input-lg" name="srchYear">
<option value="">Select Year</option>
<option value="2021"> 2021</option>
<option value="2020"> 2020</option>
<option value="2019"> 2019</option>
</select>
```

But is not working, the results have the wrong date but the right State. I first I thought was a Mac Os issue because I could see the right results but my client don't, but I'm pretty sure was a cached version, now I got the wrong results on Windows too. I tought could be a plugin, but I did a troubleshooting test with no plugins, a different theme, etc, and still didn't work,
The same script is here:
https://calendar.powwows.com/
And works perfect.

I have no idea why is not working, is a javascript incompatibility?, is something blocking it?. I got a bunch of errors in the browser Console but none is related with this issue.
I really have no clue what is wrong here.

Comment: It seems to be working for me. I selected May 2019, and the value of the hidden input was set to `2019-05-01,2019-05-28`

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section title "Write a title that summarizes the question". The current title doesn't say anything about the question.

Comment: @Barmar,Yes, for some unknown reason is working again, even on mobile, I seriously I have no clue what happened. Since 3 days ago and early today was showing only 2019 dates, no matter which date you selected and  now is working for me on pc and mobile (android), I hope is working on Mac Os too.